# merge two applications to one application on play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have two applications on play store with the same developer account named A,B which was created separately, Now I want to make this into one app, Is it Possible?
Application A ( old one ) that I do not support it now but there are still have users use it, I want to keep there users and merge the old app with new app (old users just have to update the old app to get the new app).

Comment: Not possible .. u need to migrate your users .. Maybe show an Screen on first one which will redirect them to the new one .. you can use Deep link data to validate the user if possible in your case ..

Comment: @ADM This means that I can not merge two applications into one application on Google Play?

Comment: no google play will not play any part in this .. you need send out an update of your app to do the above thing .. and handle everything by yourself .